# Perturbation of discrete dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems

Suppose we have a discrete dynamical system
$$x_{k+1}=M(x_k)$$
where $M(x)$ is a diffeomorphism and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

We have a fixed point of the system $\rho$,  ($M(\rho)=\rho$) that satisfies: $DM(x)_{x=\rho}$ has no eigenvalues $\lambda=1$.

How would we proof that if we add a perturbation to the system:
$$x_{k+1}=M(x_k)+\epsilon Q(x_k) $$ 
where $Q(x)$ is another diffeomorphism, the new system has a new fixed point $x(\epsilon)$ and $\left|x(\rho)-\rho \right|=\mathcal{O}(\epsilon) $.

Comment: Ever heard of the inverse function theorem?